# Cannot alter column 'column_name' because it is 'REPLICATED'

Tags: alter-table

I am trying alter a Column however replication is not enabled or cdc.  I am getting error Cannot alter column 'column_name' because it is 'REPLICATED'. I ran below TSQL

SELECT * FROM SYS.tables
WHERE NAME=N'ac_payment_info';

is_replicated=0

[image]

I would appreciate any help or workaround.

Answer (score 8):

Im my case I had to disable the CDC on that table (sys.sp_cdc_disable_table), alter the column, and enable de CDC again (sys.sp_cdc_enable_table). It worked.
I do not use replication.